# Convert bytes into BufferedReader in python

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, io, buffer

I have a bytearray and want to convert into a buffered reader. A way of doing it is to write the bytes into a file and read them again.

```
sample_bytes = bytes('this is a sample bytearray','utf-8')
with open(path,'wb') as f:
    f.write(sample_bytes)
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    extracted_bytes = f.read()
print(type(f))
```

output:

```
<class '_io.BufferedReader'>
```

But I want these file-like features without having to save bytes into a file. In other words I want to wrap these bytes into a buffered reader so I can apply `read()` method on it without having to save to local disk. I tried the code below

```
from io import BufferedReader
sample_bytes=bytes('this is a sample bytearray','utf-8')
file_like = BufferedReader(sample_bytes)
print(file_like.read())
```

but I'm getting an attribute error

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

How to I write and read bytes into a file like object, without saving it into local disc ?

Comment: `import io; file_like  = io.BytesIO(sample_bytes)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If all you are looking for is an in-memory file-like object, I would be looking at

```
from io import BytesIO
file_like = BytesIO(b'this is a sample bytearray')
print(file_like.read())
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass this to a `requests.post`'s `files` parameter, and it doesn't work. When I open the binary file and pass that it works.