# post file taken frob bytes array with requests.request

Tags: python, python-requests

Having following code for `POST` request with file attached:

```
        file = open(file_name, 'rb')
        files = {'file': file}

        import requests
        res = requests.request(method='POST', url=port_url, files=files, data=params)
```

`file` here of type `<class '_io.BufferedReader'>`.

Now I am trying to impliment similar with file body received by me from incoming email attachment as bytes array (want to avoid storing file to local disk):

```
        file = file_body
        files = {'file': file}

        import requests
        res = requests.request(method='POST', url=port_url, files=files, data=params)
```

and it doesn't work for some reason. Not sure what is wrong actually but external service (CloudConvert) I am trying to send unable to recognize file correctly.
Here `file` of type `<class 'bytes'>`.

Tried to convert it to `BytesIo` or `BufferedReader` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198948/convert-bytes-into-bufferedreader-in-python) without luck.

Could someone help me to `post` file taken from bytes array with `requests.request`?

Comment: Show us your BytesIO attempt. BytesIO should be the way to go.

Comment: By adding `file.name = file_name` after `file = io.BytesIO(file_body)` it started to work. E.g. cloudconvert service I am using needs proper file name to work correctly. Probably it checks for extension. Thank you, Monica!

Comment: documentation for [API](https://cloudconvert.com/api/v2#overview) shows special module for this: [cloudconvert-python](https://github.com/cloudconvert/cloudconvert-python)