# Passing BytesIO to BufferedReader results in warning message

Tags: python, minio, bytesio

I am trying to create a BufferedReader from a BytesIO object but my IDE (PyCharm) is warning me that BufferedReader `Expected type 'RawIOBase', got 'BytesIO' instead`.

The logic seems to work but I'd like to solve this properly if there is a way to do so.

Another way to phrase this question would be: can `BufferedReader` wrap a `BytesIO` object or can it only do so with objects that extend the `RawIOBase` interface?

Minimum reproducible code below:

```
from io import BytesIO, BufferedReader

b_handle = BytesIO()
b_handle.write(b"Hello World")
b_handle.seek(0)

# Warning: Expected type 'RawIOBase', got 'BytesIO' instead

br = BufferedReader(b_handle)

data = br.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: If you have a `BytesIO`, then it's already in-memory so the buffering wouldn't really buy you much - or I might be missing the use case?

Comment: Existing answers on this suggest just using the `BytesIO` directly, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198948/convert-bytes-into-bufferedreader-in-python

Comment: You're right, using the `BytesIO` object directly does work.